# Call XML items through flash based on date

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash

I have a Health Tips flash animation that i want to show one tip every day. 
I created an xml with 365 items one for each day. Now i want to link my flash with xml in order to get the correct tip for the specific day.

I created the XML using two methods.. which one do you think is the best?

```
<data>

<Tip date="28/03/2012" title="Start your day with breakfast." description="Breakfast fills your empty tank to get you going after a long night without food. "/>

</data>
```

And the other XML

```
<data>
<title name="Start your day with breakfast.">
    <description>Breakfast fills your "empty tank" to get you going after a long night without food. </description>
</title>

<title name="Eat more grains, fruits and vegetables.">
    <description>These foods give you carbohydrates for energy, plus vitamins, minerals and fiber. Besides, they taste good! Try breads such as whole-wheat, bagels and pita. </description>
</title>

</data>
```

Now I need to code my flash movie to get it working, but unfortunately don’t know how.

I started with some basic stuff:

```
var my_date:Date = new Date();

var months:Array = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"];

var dateStr = ((months[my_date.month]).toString())+"_"+ my_date.date.toString()+"_"+ my_date.fullYear.toString();

//Create the loader, set dataFormat to text 
var loadFile:URLLoader = new URLLoader()
loadFile.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT
loadFile.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadXML)
loadFile.load(new URLRequest("flash1.xml"));
function onLoadXML(ev:Event){
try{
    //Convert the downloaded text into an XML
    var myXML:XML = new XML(ev.target.data)
    var list:XMLList = myXML..title
    //walks the list and show in textfields
    for(var i=0; i<list.length(); i++){
        //trace(list[i].@name+"-"+list[i].comments+" - "+list[i].image)
    this["Title_txt"+i].text = list.@title
    this["description_txt"+i].text = list.description


    }
} catch (e:TypeError){
    //Could not convert the data
    trace("Could not parse the XML")
    trace(e.message)
}
}
```

I cant get it work properly, thus asking for help. If you please help me out with the date issue and as3 code would be great.

Thank you and waiting for your answer

Helen

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a `for each` loop instead of a regular `for`?
Also, `var list:XMLList=myXml.title` is good enough. `..title` is not needed.

```
function onLoadXML(ev:Event){
try{
    //Convert the downloaded text into an XML
    var myXML:XML = new XML(ev.target.data);
    var list:XMLList = myXML.title;
    //walks the list and show in textfields
    for each(var title:XML in list){
        this["Title_txt"+i].text = title.@name
        this["description_txt"+i].text = title.description;
    }
} catch (e:TypeError){
    //Could not convert the data
    trace("Could not parse the XML")
    trace(e.message)
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer...it makes it simpler in a way...though i still have a problem with the date function to load specific date

Comment: Well, your code shows that you didn't even try to do the date thing. I have NO idea whatsoever what you want with the "date function". Why don't you elaborate?